# How to test Max Open Websocket Limit in Tornado ( Python ) Server

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I'm trying to get Maximum number of open connection to websockets server. I've simple code in Python. which give me 28K open connection, but I think there may be something wrong in server or client code.

**Server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []

    def open(self):
        self.clients.append(self)
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
        #self.clients.remove(self)
        pass
        #print 'closed connection'

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application,no_keep_alive=False)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**Client**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Connect websockets in concurrency, 
each connection should be open until last connection made and 
server did not response 
"""

import sys
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
from websocket import create_connection



#------------
# Functions 
#------------
def send_hello(n):
    my_count = 0
    while True:
        ws = create_connection(ws_link)
        ws.send("Hello World")
        recv = ws.recv()
        if recv:
           print "-----------------------"
           print "I'm Connection : %r" % n
           print "Sending 'Hello World'"
           print "Received : %s" % recv
           my_count = my_count + 1 
           #ws.close()  # Do not close the connections,
                     # Let's see how much server can handle.. 
           print "I've sent %r messeges to server" % my_count
           print "-----------------------"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "\nUsage:\n\t %r <ws_link> <number_of_connection>\n" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1) 
    ws_link, number_of_connections = sys.argv[1:]
    # patches stdlib to cooperate with other greenlets
    #monkey.patch_thread()
    try:
       monkey.patch_all()
       jobs = [ gevent.spawn(send_hello,i) for i in range(int(number_of_connections)) ]
       gevent.wait(jobs)
    except Exception as e:
       print "Error : %r" % e
       sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you need a global client list. Your server code currently has a client list for each client which contains only itself.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
clients = []

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):


    def open(self):
        clients.append(self)
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):

        clients.remove(self)
        pass
        #print 'closed connection'

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application,no_keep_alive=False)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: This actually is not true. `clients` is being initialized at the time of class evaluation, hence that isn't a factor here at all. `self.clients.append` isn't wrong. Although, it'd be better if it were capitalized to signify a class variable.

Comment: It is wrong, check it to see if you ever have more than 2 clients in the list.
`self.clients` designates an instance variable because `self` designates the instance. So can't work.  Try the solution I suggest and see if it work.